# how will IOT (internet of things) influence UX Design

Tags: users, internet

Been hearing and reading up a lot about how the internet of things will change the way we use the internet. As designers that are just getting used to designing for the increasing amount of mobile and tablet devices, Its both exciting and scary to imagine how this will effect how we design and what future interfaces will look like. Will screen's get even smaller? what are your thoughts about this?

Comment: While this is an interesting discussion, it doesn't fit within the format of a QnA site, and so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think UX influences IOT and not the other way round. Placing technology before experience will result in bad design. I would like to quote Steve Jobs here:

> " You’ve got to start with the customer experience and work backwards
>   to the technology. You can’t start with the technology and try to
>   figure out where you’re going to try to sell it. And I’ve made this
>   mistake probably more than anybody else in this room. And I’ve got the
>   scar tissue to prove it. And I know that it’s the case.
>
> And as we have tried to come up with a strategy, and a vision for
>   Apple, um, it started with … what incredible benefits can we give to
>   the customer? Where can we take the customer? Not starting
>   with — let’s sit down with the engineers and figure out what awesome
>   technology we have, and then how are we going to market that. Um … and
>   I think that’s the right path to take."

For example:

Before iPhone, smartphones were not entirely user friendly. They required stylus, were bulky and user had to perform several actions to perform a simple task. Apple thought about a **better experience first** and invented technology around it.

I think IOT is all about providing better and connected experience to the user. Before thinking of an IOT solution, I would first think about the value addition in terms of experience.

*IMO, Future interfaces will provide a seamless integration between the physical and virtual world. It will be a more connected experience.* Ultimately, our experience will drive the future technology.

Just my $0.02. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question has a clear answer and we can only speculate where things are going. However, a very interesting question nonetheless and here are my two cents.

With smart watches I think (touch) screens can't get much smaller and stay useful. Apple already acknowledged this by placing 'the crown' on the watch, givin' the user tactile feedback on his actions. For conveying more complex information or interaction it's connected to the phone and I think this is the way things are going. Instead of placing screens everywhere, a lot of information will be passed to devices that already have a screen (like a phone or tablet). Take a thermostat for example; does it really need to be attached to the wall? Or would a web-interface be better?